# InstallShield 2012 - Add Shortcut to Start Screen

Tags: installshield

I'm using InstallShield 2012 Pro, and I want to create a shortcut to my program on the Windows 8 Start Screen.  Where do I put my shortcut?

I placed the shortcut in the Programs Menu folder and its not working,  Here's a screen shot of where I'm putting the shortcut.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Anywhere that previously showed up in the start menu (except maybe the Startup folder) is flattened into the Windows 8 start screen. So place your shortcut somewhere under `ProgramMenuFolder` and you're good to go. I would suggest still following the usual conventions so that it shows up in something like `[ProgramMenuFolder]\Company Name\Program Name` on a machine with the start menu, because even if you limit your program to Windows 8 and later, there's no predicting which way Microsoft will go next.

Comment: its not working for me, I edited my question to include a screen shot of where I'm putting the shortcut.

Comment: Are you testing on a clean (reverted) image? If you've already installed this application on the same image, and selected to unpin the shortcut from the start screen, Windows will remember this and the shortcut will not show up on future installations. Try looking at all "All Apps" to see if it is present.

Comment: I am using a clean image every time I install, and the shortcut is in the All Apps section

Comment: Does any of the information related to your shortcut, including name and possibly resources on the target exe, seem like it might be thought of as an uninstallation or help shortcut? Windows tries not to promote those as it prefers other places for these activities.